# Better way to achieve dynamic array

Tags: java, arrays

With java,

I can do this

```
String[] args = {"FOO", "BAR"};
```

I can't do this.

```
String[] args;

args={"FOO", "BAR"};
```

So doing

```
String[] args = null;
if(condition){
    String[] foobar = { "Foo", "Bar" }  ;
     args  = foobar;
}else{
    String[] fooferBarer = { "Foofer", "Barer" }  ;
     args  = fooferBarer;
}



//use args here .....
```

That looks pretty odd ..Any better ways this ??

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To instantiate an array on a line other than the declaration line, you can use:

```
String[] args;
args = new String[] {"FOO", "BAR"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because if you have one line declaration and the instantiate a `String` array then an implicit `new` is called. So you have to explicitly call `new` to instantiate.

Consider this code:

```
String[] args;
```

As it is now, `args` is only a reference variable and does not point to any object. To point to an object you have to call `new` explicitly like to instantiate it:

```
args = new String[] {"FOO", "BAR"};
```

Or you can use `ArrayList<String>` which inside use array as data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for dynamic arrays

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use ArrayList for dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList as,

```
ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add("Foo");
args.add("Bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

Any way you have to initialize your `array`. So

```
 String[] args;
 args = new String[int size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `String[] args = {"FOO", "BAR"};` is a rule of Java syntax. You can initiate the array with the values, But `args={"FOO", "BAR"};` is syntactically wrong, Because this is Java, not Python. So you should initiate the array like this `args= new String[]{"FOO", "BAR"};`

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this:

```
String[] args;

args={"FOO", "BAR"};
```

because args doesnt initialized before you doing this args={"FOO", "BAR"}

ways to solve it:

1)

```
String[] args = new String[]{"foo","bar"};
```

2)

```
String[] args; // here args is NULL 
args = new String[] {"FOO", "BAR"};
```

3) I would sugest you this way instead of using String[] use List, as for me more flexible and looks better:

```
List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>(); // in a case Java 7 use new ArrayList<>();
args.add("foo");
args.add("bar");
```